# Pass request.user to modelformset_factory() in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My goal is to create a modelformset that has a field which is a foreignkey to another model.  I want to restrict the drop down in the foreign key field depending on the user that is logged in.

models.py

```
class WeeklyWinner(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League')
    week = models.IntegerField()
    manager = models.ForeignKey('Managers')

class League(models.Model):
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    number_players = models.IntegerField()
    league_fee = models.IntegerField()
    commissioner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    deadline_date = models.DateField(help_text='Date league fees are due')
    fine = models.IntegerField(help_text = 'Amount you will charge fantasy managers that pay late', )
    draft_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Not Required')
    transaction_amount = models.IntegerField(help_text='Amount your league will charge for each transaction at the end of the season', )
    payment_info = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='Instruct your league managers on how to pay up.  You can place in a paypal link, venmo or tell them to pay you straight cash.')
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='This information will be included in the email that will be sent to league managers.  Provide any extra information on your league that you want them to know.')
    number_weeks = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, help_text='Number of weeks your league contains.  This is used to determine the number of weekly winners.')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.league_name

class Managers(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League')
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email_1 = models.EmailField()
    first_name_2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name_2 = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    email_2 = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

forms.py

```
class WeeklyWinnerForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(WeeklyWinnerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['manager'].queryset = Managers.objects.filter(league_id = 2)
        print self.user

    class Meta:
        model = WeeklyWinner
        fields = ['week', 'manager']
```

views.py

```
def weeklywinner(request):
    league = get_object_or_404(League, commissioner=request.user)
    weeklywinner = WeeklyWinner.objects.filter(league_id=league)
    weeklywinnerformset = modelformset_factory(WeeklyWinner, form=WeeklyWinnerForm, max_num=10)
    form_data = request.POST if request.method == 'POST' else None
    form = weeklywinnerformset(data=form_data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/dashboard')
    return render(request, 'settings.html', {'form': form})
```

In my forms.py if i set league_id to a hardcoded number I get my desirable results.  To pull this off I need to pass request.user to my form/formset but any attempt to pass the user variable as so:

```
form = weeklywinnerformset(data=form_data, user=request.user)
```

I get the following error code:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/weeklywinner/

Django Version: 1.5.8
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'ledger',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'after_response')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  113.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/tightflks/Documents/EAV/clients/fantasy/fantasy_development/ledger/views.py" in weeklywinner
  379.     form = weeklywinnerformset(data=form_data, user=request.user)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  441.         super(BaseModelFormSet, self).__init__(**defaults)

Exception Type: TypeError at /weeklywinner/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'
```

Answer (score 0):

Django internally uses modelform_factory function in modelformset_factory which doesn't considers any overriden methods or custom fields, it only uses Meta attributes of the Form class given (in your case "WeeklyWinnerForm") like fields, exclude etc, so **init** of WeeklyWinnerForm is never called, to do that you have to implement your custom modelformset_factory.

Comment: Are you sure its not called?  because `self.fields['manager'].queryset = Managers.objects.filter(league_id = 2)` returns my desired results, so that part of the code is being called